# Which Stack Exchange can I ask about modifying the Leitner system?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about modifying the Leitner system (a system on learning based on the use of flashcards). It's a little complex and might require mathematical analysis (or logical analysis) but I am unsure if my question fits any of the Stack Exchange sites. I've looked at User Experience and Academia but I am unsure.

My question would be for a solution regarding how to organize my flashcards if they have more than one piece of information on them.

#

Attempt at asking the question to help with guidance

#

Well, I don't know how much math I would get into, I'm kind of weary of providing too much information because then I will just ask the question here haha. But I might as well try since the math is kind of a mess to understand and it might help to get me the question in a more finalized form.

Basically I want to use the leitner system but the flashcards that I've bought have more than one element of information on them so splitting them is  not so black and white.

I will use the example of the leitner system which is on wikipedia (Which in and of itself is very confusing)

From what I can make of this example.

First one has to decide the maximum amount of times you want to encounter a card if you always know it.
4 times
Then one has to decide the number of times between each successful attempt
1day - 2days - 3days - 4days

And then it took me a while to figure out the wikipedia example but let me try to clear it up.

You orgnaize your bins to the total amount of days in your intervals 
so 1day + 2days + 3days + 4days = 10 bins

And I just don't know how to describe this:

```
 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 Represents the days of each session
 --------------------------------------
 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 'These numbers going down represent the next
 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 'session the cards in these bins will be 
 9 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 'reviewed
```

So the above if it is clear sets the session for individual cards, so I'm simply wondering if there is a way to easily demark different stacks for when you want to know one piece of infomation in one deck and another in another deck.

Example. Learning Chinese language. 
You have the chinese character on the card and it's meaing
but you could seperate this information into three different compartments
Recoginition: Recognizing the sound and tone this character makes
Definition: it's meaning
Writing: How to write it.

So if i wanted to compartmentalize these three pieces of information as different but keep them on the same card, how could I move a successful attempt at recognition into it's progressive bin, all the while demoting an unsucessful attempt and defining or writing the term?

Is it possible to make some sort of complex box like the above? Or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Did you ask this somewhere in the end? I'd be interested to read both the full question and the answers. If there's nowhere at Stack Exchange, try Reddit.

Comment: @ruffle based on the history I don't think I ever did. Or it got deleted. I have my own formula that I figured out but I also never applied it anywhere. Basically I wanted and still trying to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime

Answer (score 1):

User Experience seems way off.

My first instinct would be to try [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com).

I'm not sure, though. Any chance you could elaborate on your question? I know you said it has to do with organizing flash cards, but how involved is it? Would you cross into mathematical or logical analysis?

Comment: I added what I would post as a question if that helps, I have a feeling though that it's just hard to clearly explain.